# Import Excel (.xlsx) data using C# as strings

Tags: c#, excel, import, excel-2010

I am trying to import data from an .xlsx document. It keeps reading the data types incorrectly. I need every column to come in as a string.

My connection string looks like this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + FileName + "; Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = Yes; IMEX = 1';"
```

Comment: Specify _"incorrectly"_.

Comment: Have you looked at this?

[Reading Excel InterMixed DataType Without Modifying Registry Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936646/reading-excel-intermixed-datatype-without-modifying-registry-key)

Comment: IMEX uses a tiny row sampling to determine the datatype, if you have 20 numeric value then 100k strings your out of luck as its decided the column is numeric

Comment: Good to know about IMEX. Yes, my columns appear to be numeric for the first 700 rows, and then begin to display string characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try something like [linqtoexcel](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) this turns excel worksheets into objects which can be queried using linq queries. Then you can turn columns into string if you want to by quering the linq objects.