# OleDb ignores the texts starting with 0

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbdataadapter

I'm using OleDbDataAdapter

I'm trying to get data from excel to DataTable, Here is my code;

```
var conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        var myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(" SELECT * FROM [UPLOADFILE$] ", strConn);
        var inputTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            myCommand.Fill(inputTable);
        }
```

Here is my Conn Str;

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                          "Data Source=" + "MyPath" + ";" +
                          "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
```

Somehow, It eliminates the strings starting with "0", but others are okay.

I used the following combinations, as well;

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                      "Data Source=" + "MyPath" + ";" +
                      "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=0;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";

"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                      "Data Source=" + "MyPath" + ";" +
                      "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";

"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                      "Data Source=" + "MyPath" + ";" +
                      "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
```

Thanks in advance!

My Tries;

```
Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with connection to say "Somehow, It eliminates the strings starting with "0""? Please post some minimal but complete code for people to execute it and see. What do you expect the code to do?

Comment: Hi @shahkalpesh, I'm trying to read data from excel.

Comment: what is the cell value in the Excel Formula bar?

Comment: @Slai, at Excel 0323, at DataTable "". Other ex is; at Excel 1234, at DataTable "1234". Only text starting with 0s are eliminated.

Comment: you can try without `TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936646/reading-excel-intermixed-datatype-without-modifying-registry-key

Comment: @Slai Thank you for your answer! I tried. This time, the missing out values are seen correctly, but other values are shown wrong. Results; 2.3305e+009
0730311111
3051411111
1.44091e+010. The result with e's are not correct, but others(0730311111) are correct.

Comment: @ÖzerErdönmez OLEDB usually gets only the actual value without the Number Format that you probably see in the cell. That is why I asked to check the value in the Excel Formula Bar instead of the cell. To get the Number format, you can try Office Interop or some of the .xlsx libraries such as OpenXML, ClosedXML, EPPlus, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this is my go-to connection string for reading excel via OleDb.

```
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
    filename + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'; ";
```

For what it's worth I tried it on some data and had no issues when I had text with leading zeroes.

Is your data in a table or is it just a standard range?  Does it have headers?  Can you show some sample data that is erroring out?

Comment: Not standart range. It ranges 7 to 11 digits. Yes, it has header.