How to force SSIS to read data in a specific data type - that was used in the task configuration?
I'm looping over excel files in a folder using the foreach task, reading the file (using the variable loaded by the foreach task), the first row is the header, and loading data into SQL table.
When doing the development, I am working with a file that has the following columns:
ID, Name, InternalName, Date
The InternalName can have text or numeric data. Irrespective, I want this to be read as text.
When configuring the excel data source task, when I use the sample file which has all InternalName values as text, SSIS correctly identifies the data type (based on the first 8 rows). Running the package works as expected and loads data into the SQL table.

At this point I am expecting that the excel data source task must remember the configured data types (that is - InternalName must be always read as text). Is this assumption incorrect? This question arises because when I run the program, and it loops over several excel files (using filename variable loaded by the foreach task), for each file it seems to recheck the first 8 rows to figure out the data type. I think so because:


a. If majority of the first 8 rows are numeric, then any text value gets returned as NULL

b. If majority of first 8 rows are Text or NULL, then any numeric value gets returns as NULL
Why does SSIS reattempt to check what is the data type for each file, and attempt to read the column in a different format to what I have setup during the original configuration (wherein I had used a good example with all values of InternalName as Text)?



What is the solution to this?


a. I tried using the excel advanced editor's Input columns section to force the data type, but this gets reset after the data preview.

b. I tried using the excel advanced editor's External columns section to force the data type, but this doesn't seem to work as well.

c. I thought of using the data conversion or derived task, but as the data itself isn't read correctly by the excel task, these seem pointless.

d. I tried using IMEX=1 in the excel connection string but this isn't making any difference to the behaviour. Maybe because first row is headers?



I have a vague memory that there's a registry setting to force excel drivers to look through the whole file when determining the data type. BTW, the excel reading is a nightmare for some reason, I wouldn't use a microsoft tool to do it

You cannot force ACE to read the columns in a specific data type. It infers them (sometimes incorrectly). Honestly, avoid Excel files if you can. CSV files are better in my opinion, if you want data in a "worksheet" like format, as you can be explicit.

Try the registry thing in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936646/reading-excel-intermixed-datatype-without-modifying-registry-key perhaps?

I cannot change anything in the registry as that is not allowed. But I get your point.
